# How to implement grails bean

Tags: grails, javabeans

In my grails application, there are ten domain classes, in every domain class there is one comment field which is common. It compromises of current authenticated user with current time-stamp.

How can I implement the above said comments using beans

Comment: How about [Inheritance](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceInGORM)?

Comment: Please,try to edit you question  in more detail manner !!

Answer (score 0):

## Create a comment Domain class

```
class comment 
{
   String message;
   static belongsTo=[User]  //add or can leave it , for all your ten domains

}
```

Then you need to associate it with let say to Ten of your domain class ,ex.User

```
class User {

    String UserName
    static hasMany=[comments:Comment] // if you have many commentin one pass or
    Comment comment  ///just one to one relationship for every login one record 

     }
```

## And the Bean ,

You can create a commentService for just operating on the comment and your domain class,grails create a DI bean automatically after you create a commentService on services
and you could have some sample service method which will be injected

```
         def registerInfo (){

           //do some comment and domin related stuff
             }

          like in a controller login 

         def commentService 

         def signin(){

          commentService.registerInfo(params)

          }
```